# NPSP with custom record types

Tags: npsp

We have created custom record types for Account and Opp, but upon lead conversion it always results in an organization and donation type even though we have removed npsp's lead convert page and using the standard. Is there a way to use custom record types with npsp?

Comment: have you checked the record types are enabled for the profiles you are using and that the NPSP ones are not the default?

Comment: @dave yes, I have done that yet it results in npsp's record type after conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to specify custom Account record type in NPSP lead conversion or in standard conversion.  You would have to write a custom lead conversion process with Apex that creates the account record before converting the lead, then sets the account ID in the LeadConvert class and then proceeds with lead conversion.